# One client is not receiving message from another client

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, connection, client-server

My problem I can't fix is that when one client sends a message, the second client doesn't receive it, and vice versa.

I have understood that with `client.send(message)` in the server script, it sends the message to all the clients, i.e., you don't need to tell to *who* to send it.

### My codes:

#### Code for client

```html
import socket
import threading

class sendThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip
        self.client = client
        print "[+] New send thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port) + "...Everything went successful!"

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = raw_input("Enter command:")
            self.client.send(data)

class receiveThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, client):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.client = client
        print "[+] New receive thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port) + "...Everything went successful!"

    def run(self):
        print "Entered run method"
        size = 1024
        while True:
            data = self.client.recv(size)
            if data != "" or data:
                print data


def client():
    port = 1724
    ip = '127.0.0.1'
    print "Connection from : "+ip+":"+str(port)
    client = socket.socket()
    client.connect((ip, port))
    receive = receiveThread(ip, port, client)
    print "b1"
    receive.start()
    print "b2"
    send = sendThread(ip, port, client)
    print "b3"
    send.start()
    while send.isAlive() and receive.isAlive():
        continue
    print "-----END of While TRUE------"
    print "Client disconnected..."

client()
```

#### Code for server

```html
import socket
import threading

global num
num = 0

class serverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client, address):
        global num
        num = num + 1
        self.id = num
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client
        self.address = address
        print "serverThread init finished-" + str(self.id)

    def run(self):
        print "r1 num-" + str(self.id)
        size = 1024
        while True:
            #try:
                print "r2-" + str(self.id)
                data = self.client.recv(size)
                print "r3..... " + data
                print "r4-" + str(self.id)
                if data:
                    print "r5-" + str(self.id)
                    response = data

                    self.client.send(response)
                    print "r6-" + str(self.id)
                else:
                    print "r7-" + str(self.id)
                    raise Exception('Client disconnected-' + str(self.id) )
            #except:
               # print "Except"
               # self.client.close()
               # return

def create(ipHost, port):
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind((ipHost, port))
    print "The server was created successfully."
    return server

def listen(server):
    server.listen(5)
    client, address = server.accept()
    c1 = serverThread(client, address)
    c1.start()
    client, address = server.accept()
    c2 = serverThread(client, address)
    c2.start()
    print "finished both threads created"

    while c1.isAlive() and c2.isAlive():
        continue

server = create("0.0.0.0", 1724)
listen(server)
```

Both clients have the following output:

```
Connection from : 127.0.0.1:1720
[+] New receive thread started for 127.0.0.1:1720...Everything went successful!
b1
Entered run method
b2
[+] New send thread started for 127.0.0.1:1720...Everything went successful!
b3
Enter command:Hello
Enter command:Hello
```

This is the case when both clients send the same message.

***If client 1 sends "Hello" and client 2 sends "Hi":*** Client 1 will have as output `Hello` and client 2 will have as output `Hi`, instead of both receiving `Hi` and `Hello`.